# If I cook chicken breasts in instant pot for a "longer time" would they come out super tender? I'm thinking 12 minutes or so

Tags: chicken, chicken-breast, instant-pot

I would think pressure cooking chicken breasts in the instant pot for longer, and by that I mean 12 minutes or a little more, they would come out super tender. Am I wrong? Would the opposite happen? I may try it as an experiment.

Comment: @rumtscho : the question that you claim is a duplicate might indirectly answer what happens when it's cooked too long, but it doesn't answer the main question, nor does it mention what the result is at 12 minutes of pressure cooking.

Comment: And personally, I haven't tried chicken breasts in an instant pot -- thighs handle over-cooking much better.  They basically fall apart on you when cooked right.  (I usually brown boneless skinless thighs, then stack them with sauce and mirin or some other liquid, then set for 8 minutes then quick release.  If you do a natural release, there difficult to extract as they just fall apart.)

Answer (score 1):

Time in the pressure cooker will depend on the thickness of the chicken breasts. I'd say 12-15 min on high pressure should give you meat that can be shredded easily (I've cooked a few times following some variation of [this recipe](https://recipes.instantpot.com/recipe/fiesta-chicken-tacos/), which yields similar results).

Cooking any meat on high heat (or high pressure) for an extended period will both:

- denature more the proteins / collagen making the meat more tender;
- "squeeze" more water out of the meat, making it drier / chalkier in texture.

At 12-15 min range the chicken meat will dry out some, but let it rest in the cooking liquid for a few minutes before cutting and it should be able to re-absorb some of it (or not release more).